# Create url link in menu

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, rhel, menu

How can I create a menu item that points to a URL?

I've tried creating a `mylink.desktop` entry like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=My Link Name
Icon=my-icon
Type=Link
Categories=Office;
URL=http://www.example.com/
```

then using `xdg-desktop-menu install mylink.desktop` should put this entry in the current user's menu. This does not work however. The file is copied into `~/.local/share/applications/` but the entry doesn't show up in the menu.

If I change `Type` to `Application` and define `Exec` instead of `URL` then it works. But I don't want to have menu entry for a local application. I want a default browser to launch on a specified address when the menu entry is selected.

How can I do that?

Also, by using this command: `xdg-desktop-icon install mylink.desktop` the result is as expected - a new link is created on the desktop. So why doesn't it work in the menu?

I tested this on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 with KDE, but I would like to know how to do it in Gnome as well.

Comment: I Assume you mean RedHat Enterprise 6 (RHEL 6) or perhaps even Fedora 6, but RedHat 6 itself is 10 years old now and a bit obsolete.

Comment: @penguin oh yeah, I meant RHEL 6, sorry ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While reading up on stuff I stumbled uppon [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/send-file-to-opened-editor-using-command-line). That gave me an idea for a workaround:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=My Link Name
Icon=my-icon
Type=Application
Categories=Office;
Exec=xdg-open http://www.example.com/
```

This does exactly what I need and is a local application, so I can use `xdg-desktop-menu` to install this entry without problems.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to create a Link.directory file in /usr/share/deskop-directory. And merge this directory into the proper menus [ by editing the /etc/xdg/applications.menu, I guess. Please check the exact menu file ]

Comment: You mean to create `mylink.directory` with the same contents as `mylink.desktop` above, but add it as a new menu directory? Would this really work?

Comment: no no. Not the mylink.directory but the Link.directory. [ here Link is value you write against the "Type" variable ]

Comment: OK, could you please be more specific? What should Link.directory contain? I suppose I could add it by invoking `xdg-desktop-menu` as well instead of manually editing `/etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu`, right?

Comment: http://satishwagh.blogspot.com/2010/05/adding-sub-menu-to-main-menu.html

Comment: this doesn't help me at all. I don't want to create any custom submenu...